Are there any no-code tools for deploying ERC-20 tokens?
As the title says: are there any no-code tools for deploying ERC-20 tokens?

Yes, there exist several solutions:



Name
Website




Token Generator
https://smartcontracts.tools/token-generator


CoinFactory
https://coinfactory.app/


CreateMyToken
https://createmytoken.com/


DeFiBuiler
https://defibuilder.com


ThirdWeb
https://thirdweb.com/thirdweb.eth/TokenERC20


OpenZeppelin Wizard
https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc20




For anyone relying on these tools, be sure to test sufficiently without putting funds at risk. Have seen so many lose eth, pairing with tokens whom's mechanics they have no understanding of or how they work together.  It is possible to lose your money deploying contracts without understanding their workings.
